# Host java web service with jelastic

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl

I am working on Java web service I created the service and hosted on jelastic cloud. I am able to access the wsdl by opening it n browser for eg http:\"jel environment"\wsdl\"wsdl-name",I created the client from this url and I am trying to access with client.I got this error

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Could not send Message.
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:147)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy26.test(Unknown Source)
    at comm.ServPortType_ServPort_Client.main(ServPortType_ServPort_Client.java:53)
Caused by: org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPException: HTTP response '404: Not Found' when communicating with http://env-5147795.ind-cloud.everdata.com/testservice/services/servPort
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:1563)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:1515)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:1318)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.AbstractConduit.close(AbstractConduit.java:56)
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit.close(HTTPConduit.java:632)
    at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.MessageSenderInterceptor$MessageSenderEndingInterceptor.handleMessage(MessageSenderInterceptor.java:62)
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.doInvoke(ClientImpl.java:572)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:481)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:382)
    at org.apache.cxf.endpoint.ClientImpl.invoke(ClientImpl.java:335)
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy.invokeSync(ClientProxy.java:96)
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsClientProxy.invoke(JaxWsClientProxy.java:136)
    ... 2 more
```

Like I said I myself created the service with soap address as `localhost` I changed that to `http:\\environment jelastic\services\port\` and changed everything in client to call corresponding wsdl.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to connect to the specific port in your environment which differs from 80, 8080?
If so - you should have an external IP address (Public IPv4) in your environment.